# Some services are not able to be constructed when dynamic assembly loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, dependency-injection

I am trying to add assembly by reflection in my .net core project (DNAPI). That external project (EBiletManager) include ILogger and other required services from other common reference project (DNDomain.proj).

```
public class EBiletManager : DNDomain.IScopedProcessingService {

    ILogger _logger;
    IConfiguration _configuration;

    public EBiletManager(ILogger logger, IConfiguration configuration,

...
```

When I add the EBiletManager to DNAPI from Project Dependencies, these are working correctly.

I spend hours for this problem and I try [this](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/extensions/AppWithPlugin) plug-in methods. And I try copy all DLL references to \bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1 folder but not working.

Assembly loading correctly but "EBiletManager" constractor throw this error.

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: DNDomain.Services.IScopedProcessingService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: EBiletService.EBiletManager': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'EBiletService.EBiletManager'.)'

> 1/2: InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: DNDomain.Services.IScopedProcessingService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: EBiletService.EBiletManager': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'EBiletService.EBiletManager'.

> 2/2: InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'EBiletService.EBiletManager'.

Service description lines:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCustomServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) {
            services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();

            var loadContext = new PluginLoadContext(pluginLocation);
            var assembly = loadContext.LoadFromAssemblyName(new AssemblyName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pluginLocation)));
            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes()) {
                if (type.GetInterface(nameof(DNDomain.IScopedProcessingService)) != null) {
                    services.AddScoped(typeof(DNDomain.IScopedProcessingService), type);
                }
            }
...
```

Sorry for bad English and thanks for helps.

Comment: Please [don't post images of exceptions](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Comment: The error message indicates that you have not registered the ILogger service. I suggest that you add the ILogger registered service before the AddCustomServices method.